# What conformal map transforms two disjoint disks into two parallel lines?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Given two disjoint disks in the complex plane, can the region outside of them be conformally mapped to a region bounded by two parallel lines? I think the answer is yes because the region is simply connected (I do not know further details about the topic).

At first, I thought on using Möbius transformation, but that would work only if they had a tangent point (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520168/find-the-m%C3%B6bius-transform-that-maps-two-given-circles-to-concentric-circles)).

I am thinking of trying to construct a [Schwarz-Christoffel mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping) that would do it, but I do not know how to achieve that.

The problem I am trying to solve is to find the electric potential distribution of two parallel, non-uniformly charged conductors. I think that finding a solution through conformal mapping would be interesting.

Comment: The complement of two disjoint disks is *not* simply connected. You can however map that region (using a Möbius) to an annulus (i.e., the region between two concentric circles.

Answer (score 1):

As per a comment of Hagen von Eitzen: the complement of two disjoint disks is not simply connected. But that region can be [mapped to an annulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2229423/303899).

Assume two circles, $C_1$ and $C_2$ with radius $r_1$ and $r_2$, respectively, such that $r_1 > r_2$. Assume yet that $C_1$ is centered at the origin and $C_2$ centered over the Real axis at a point $h$. Lets transform $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that they form an annulus centered at the origin.

### The algorithm is as follows:

Find parameters $a,b,c,d$ of the Möbius transformation (can be by [explicit determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Explicit_determinant_formula)) that makes the bigger circle into a line over the Imaginary axis ($\mathbf{z} \to \mathbf{w}$).

$$
\mathbf{z} = [i\,r_1,\, -i\,r_1,\, r_1] \\
\mathbf{w} = [-i,\, i,\, \infty] \\
$$

This transformation is

$$
f(z) = \frac{a\,z + b}{c\,z + d}
$$

Move both the line and new circle by $-p$ such that the circle of radius $r_w$ is centered at the origin. Variables $p$ and $r_w$ satisfy:

$$
|w_1|^2 - 2\,\Re(w_1 \,\bar p) + |p|^2 - r_w^2 = 0 \\
|w_2|^2 - 2\,\Re(w_2 \,\bar p) + |p|^2 - r_w^2 = 0 \\
$$

Where $w_1$ and $w_2$ are points over the circle.

This transformation is
$$
g(z) = z - p
$$

Now find $x_1$ and $x_2$ (zeros of the following equation) that transforms the line into a circle around the origin while also preserving the center of the other circle around the origin.

$$
x^2 + 2\,p\,x + r_w^2 = 0
$$

This transformation is
$$
h(z) = \frac{z - x1}{z - x2}
$$

Now compose all these transformations:

$$
T(z) = h \circ g \circ f (z)
$$

$$
T(z) = \frac{b + a\,z - (p + x_1) (d + c\,z)}{b + a\,z - (p + x_2) (d + c\,z)}
$$

#### A Julia code

The following is a [Julia](https://julialang.org/) code I created that implements the above algorithm.

```
using LinearAlgebra
using NLsolve
using Polynomials
using Plots

function mobius(z, w)
    a = det([z[1]*w[1]  w[1]  1;
             z[2]*w[2]  w[2]  1;
             z[3]*w[3]  w[3]  1])
    b = det([z[1]*w[1]  z[1]  w[1];
             z[2]*w[2]  z[2]  w[2];
             z[3]*w[3]  z[3]  w[3]])
    c = det([z[1]  w[1]  1;
             z[2]  w[2]  1;
             z[3]  w[3]  1])
    d = det([z[1]*w[1]  z[1]  1;
             z[2]*w[2]  z[2]  1;
             z[3]*w[3]  z[3]  1])
    return a, b, c, d
end

function find_trans(r1, r2, h, n=200)
    infty = 1e10  # "infinity"
    θ = range(0, 2π, length=n)
    z1 = @. r1*(cos(θ) + 1im*sin(θ))
    z2 = @. r2*(cos(θ) + 1im*sin(θ)) + h
    # transforms the bigger circle into a line on the imaginary axis
    a, b, c, d = mobius([-1im*r1, 1im*r1, r1], [1im, -1im, infty])
    f(z) = (a*z + b)/(c*z + d)
    # center transformed circle on the origin
    w1 = f(z2[1])
    w2 = f(z2[cld(n,2)])
    function f!(F, x)
        F[1] = abs(w1)^2 - 2*real(w1*conj(x[1])) + abs(x[1])^2 - x[2]^2
        F[2] = abs(w2)^2 - 2*real(w2*conj(x[1])) + abs(x[1])^2 - x[2]^2
    end
    # sol.zero: center point of the transformed circle and its radius
    sol1 = nlsolve(f!, [0.0, 2r1])
    p = sol1.zero[1]
    r = sol1.zero[2]
    # transform the line into a unit circle centered at the origin,
    # while also preserving the other at the origin
    x1, x2 = roots(Poly([r^2, 2p, 1]))
    # Möbius transformation that sends x1 -> 0 and x2 -> oo,
    # where x1 and x2 are symmetric points to both the line and circle
    T(z) = (b + a*z - (p + x1)*(d + c*z))/(b + a*z - (p + x2)*(d + c*z))
    return a, b, c, d, p, r, x1, x2, T
end

begin
    n = 500
    θ = range(0, 2π, length=n)
    r1 = 2
    r2 = 1
    h = 2r1
    z1 = @. r1*(cos(θ) + 1im*sin(θ))
    z2 = @. r2*(cos(θ) + 1im*sin(θ)) + h
    a, b, c, d, p, r, x1, x2, T = find_trans(r1, r2, h)
    w1 = T.(z1)
    w2 = T.(z2)
    plot(aspect_ratio=1)#, xlim=(-l,l), ylim=(-l,l))
    plot!(z1, color=:blue, label="z1")
    scatter!(z1[1:1], color=:blue, label="")
    plot!(z2, color=:red, label="z2")
    scatter!(z2[1:1], color=:red, label="")
    plot!(w1, color=:blue, label="w1", linestyle=:dash)
    scatter!(w1[1:1], color=:blue, label="")
    plot!(w2, color=:red, label="w2", linestyle=:dash)
    scatter!(w2[1:1], color=:red, label="")
end
```

The output of the above code is the following figure.

[image: code output]

---

Now the potential problem can be solved in the annulus. See, for example, [Conformal Mapping and Bipolar Coordinate for Eccentric Laplace Problems](http://msvlab.hre.ntou.edu.tw/grades/bem(2008)/caee2009-bipolar.pdf).

### Edit

For the sake of completness, the inverse transformation is
$$
T^{-1}(z) = \frac{b - d\,(p + x_1) - b\,z + d\,(p + x_2)\,z}{a\,(z - 1) + c\,(p + x_1 - (p + x_2)\,z)}
$$